# Subsetting - R prints data in reverse order- [R 3.2.2, Win10 Pro, 64-bit]

Tags: r

**Aim**: To retrieve last two entries of data.( I am aware of the tail function, or direct indexing)

Code:

```
> tdata <- read.csv("hw1_data.csv")
> temp <- tdata[(nrow(tdata)-1):nrow(tdata), ]
> temp
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
152    18     131  8.0   76     9  29
153    20     223 11.5   68     9  30  
> temp <- tdata[nrow(tdata)-1:nrow(tdata), ]
> temp
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
152    18     131  8.0   76     9  29
151    14     191 14.3   75     9  28
150    NA     145 13.2   77     9  27
149    30     193  6.9   70     9  26
148    14      20 16.6   63     9  25
147     7      49 10.3   69     9  24
.
. 
.
```

While taking a subset using the extract operator, I have used the nrows() function to retrieve the total number of rows in the data and subtracted one from it (one less than total rows) and used sequence operator(:) to sequence till nrows(data), *i.e.* total number of rows.

When I use parentheses, the logic works fine, but when I skip the parentheses the output is the total dataframe in a **reverse order**.

I can figure out that precedence rules are at play, but unable to figure out exact logic. New at R, so any formal explanation would be valuable.

[image: Screenshot of both changes to the code:]

Comment: The `:` operator has precedence over the minus, so 100 - 1:10 is the same as 100 - (1:10), i.e. `c(99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90)`.

Comment: Take  a look at `?Syntax`.

Comment: Please, could you edit your question and include the two lines of code and the relevant parts of the output instead of linking to a screenshot? The link might break in the future. Then the question and the answers are useless for other SO users. Thank you.

Comment: @UweBlock thank you for the help. Will keep this in mind, in the future.

Comment: @RHertel thank you for the documentation link. Exactly what I needed. How can I make this the answer?

Comment: @AdityaAgrawal I'm glad it helped. I extended the comment somewhat and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected correctly in the post, the observed behavior is in fact a matter of operator precedence.

A complete list of the operator syntax and precedence rules in R can be obtained by typing

```
help(Syntax)
```

in the console.

---

In this context, R programmers sometimes refer to a well-known and rather witty quote which encourages the use of parentheses:

```
library(fortunes)
fortune(138)
```

Answer (score 2):

`nrow(tdata) = 153`

So the first line you run is:

```
temp <- tdata[(nrow(tdata)-1):nrow(tdata),]
```

This executes as `tdata[152:153,]`

Second line:

```
temp <- tdata[nrow(tdata)-1:nrow(tdata),]
```

This executes as `tdata[153-1:153,]`

So it returns the following:

```
tdata[152,]
tdata[151,]
...
tdata[0,]
```